# Unable to run a function synchronously in nodejs and express

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous, mean, node-deasync

I have used [wikipedia-js](https://github.com/kenshiro-o/wikipedia-js) for this project. This is my code for `summary.js` file.

```
var wikipedia = require("wikipedia-js");
var something = "initial";
module.exports = {
    wikitext: function(topicname) {
        console.log("Inside wikitex funciton :" + topicname);
        var options = {
            query: topicname,
            format: "html",
            summaryOnly: false,
            lang: "en"
        };

        wikipedia.searchArticle(options, function(err, htmlWikiText) {
            console.log("Inside seararticlefunciton :");

            if (err) {
                console.log("An error occurred[query=%s, error=%s]", topicname, err);
                return;
            }
            console.log("Query successful[query=%s, html-formatted-wiki-text=%s]", topicname, htmlWikiText);
            something = htmlWikiText;
        });
        return something;
    },
};
```

This module I am using in `/wiki/:topicname` route. The corresponding code in `index.js` is like this.

```
router.get('/wiki/:topicname', function(req, res, next) {
    var topicname = req.params.topicname;
    console.log(topicname);
    var first = summary.wikitext(topicname);
    res.send("Hello "+first);
});
```

The problem is, everytime i visit a wiki/***some-topic***, the last return statement of `summary.js` executes before `htmlWikiText` is populated with content. So I always see `hello initial` on the browser page. Although after sometime it gets printed on terminal due to `console.log` statement.

So how should I resolve this issue?

Comment: It is likely impossible to make it synchronous, read the docs for `wikipedia` to find out for sure. Either way, making it synchronous is a HORRIBLE idea anyway in your situation because it will lock down your server for a period of time, making it unable to respond to any requests.

Comment: so how can I return the value only after the above function has finished execution? also nothing of synchronous or asynchronous is mentioned in the docs.

Comment: you can't, that's impossible. you must use a callback.

Comment: ok. I tried using callback in wikipedia.searchArticle function, but isn't working. How should use callback in that function?

Comment: You'll need to understand callbacks in order to successfully work with nodejs. Read an article like github.com/maxogden/art-of-node#callbacks and you'll be able to answer your own question.

Comment: ok thanks for the reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not going to try turning this code into synchronous.  I'll just correct it to work as an asynchronous version.

You need to pass in callback to wikitext() and return the value in that callback.  Here is the revised code of wikitext() and the route that calls it:

```
var wikipedia = require("wikipedia-js");
module.exports = {
    wikitext: function(topicname, callback) {
        console.log("Inside wikitex funciton :" + topicname);
        var options = {
            query: topicname,
            format: "html",
            summaryOnly: false,
            lang: "en"
        };

        wikipedia.searchArticle(options, function(err, htmlWikiText) {
            console.log("Inside seararticlefunciton :");
            if (err) {
                console.log("An error occurred[query=%s, error=%s]", topicname, err);
                return callback(err);
            }
            console.log("Query successful[query=%s, html-formatted-wiki-text=%s]", topicname, htmlWikiText);
            callback(null, htmlWikiText);
        });
    }
};


router.get('/wiki/:topicname', function(req, res, next) {
    var topicname = req.params.topicname;
    console.log(topicname);
    summary.wikitext(topicname, function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            return res.send(err);
        }
        if (!result) {
            return res.send('No article found');
        }
        res.send("Hello "+result);

    });
});
```